# Show Spinner selection in text view

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I have changed my code with local debug not showing any errors. The problem I have is that I'm struggling to work out how to show the selected spinner text in the textview (txtMarquee) which is a scrolling text.

I do not know what code to use I am quiet new and still watching many tutorials and not having any luck.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txtMarquee;
    Spinner spinnerV;

    Button btnAdmin;

    Button btnSelect;
    Button btnRefresh;
    DatabaseReference spinnerRef;
    ArrayList<String> spinnerList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);            

        txtMarquee = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.marqueeText);

        btnSelect = findViewById(R.id.Selectbtn);
        
        txtMarquee.setSelected(true);

        btnRefresh=findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
        btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent2); finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        });
    
        btnAdmin=findViewById(R.id.btnAdmin);
        btnAdmin.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent=new Intent( MainActivity.this, Admin_login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        });

        spinnerV = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        spinnerRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Spinner");

        spinnerList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerList);

        spinnerV.setAdapter(adapter);
        Showdata();

    }

    private void Showdata() {
        spinnerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot item : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    spinnerList.add(Objects.requireNonNull(item.getValue()).toString());    
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }
        });    
    }    
}
```

Comment: 1. What part of the code you shared doesn't work? Any error message? 2. Also how is this code related to the `mTxt` that you want to update? 3. Finally: **stop ignoring potential errors** and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: The code works fully there are no errors, To clarify I don't know what code needs to be added to make what I want to do work. What needs to be added to this code and other files to make it work. For example I tred: spinnerList.add(item.getValue().toString()) I took this and used mTxt.setText(R.string.spinnerList); which didn't work

Comment: That's useful to know. Instead of adding that information in a comment, click the little `edit` link under your question and update your question with the additional information. Also note #3 in my comment on handling errors. --- With the updated code, you'll want to then debug the problem locally and add the result of that too. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited the code above, no errors on debug, I really am struggling on how to show the selected text from the spinner to the textview.